# 3D transform loses perspective at the end of the transition

Tags: css, transform, perspective, css-transforms

So I've got my code like this, wanting the bg1 div to be rotated from the left in a certain angle, but as you may see, at the end, it "loses perspective", as I see it, although i'm probably wrong. What do you think i'm doing wrong or what can I do to achieve my goal?

Code of the simple page:

```
    <style>
    #bg1{
        position:absolute;
        left:0px;
        top:0px;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        background-color:orange;

        font-size:100px;
        font-family:Arial;
        color:white;
        text-align:center;

        -webkit-transform: perspective(100px); 
        -webkit-transform-origin:left;
        transition:1s;
    }
    #bg1:active{
        -webkit-transform:rotateY(85deg);
    }
    </style>

    <body>
    <div id="bg1"></div>
    </body>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the perspective **also** on the active state, since it is inside he transform:

```
#bg1:active{
    -webkit-transform: perspective(100px) rotateY(85deg);
}
```

Otherwise, you are transitioning to a rotated, but without perspective, element. (of course in the middle of the transition it still has some perspective)